# No value given for one of more required parameters

Tags: excel, vba

I am not a programmer so the below code was not created by me. I was trying to replicate one of the functions for a new account and i've been running into an error at this line:

```
rs.Open "Select * From " & file2 & ".txt order by [Security]", _
       conn, adOpenStatic, adLockUnspecified, adCmdText
```

The file that it's referencing is similar to the other files so i am unsure on what the problem could be. I checked all the spelling and i just can't figure it out. Some help or just even how to troubleshoot would be much appreciated.

```
Public Sub RunRecon()
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    ReconLDSF
    ReconUCAL
    ReconCNSL
    ReconMONT
    ReconMAC50
    ReconMAC40
    ReconTOU
    ReconVER
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    End Sub
    Function ReconTOU()
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim adcomm As New ADODB.Command
    Dim path As String
    Dim loDataWrk As Worksheet
    Set loDataWrk = Worksheets("TOU")

    loDataWrk.Range("A3:AZ5000").ClearContents
    path = "L:\ForumAxys\ForumImports\Mellon\Versus\"
    conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE" _


 & ".OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & path _
    & ";Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;" _
    & "FMT=Delimited'"

rs.Open "Select * from [Custody Holdings.csv] where [Account Number] = '492617' and [Traded Shares/Par] <> '0' order by [Security Description 1]", _
     conn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

cnt = 3
Name = "NA"

Do While Not rs.EOF
If Left(rs.Fields("Security Description 1"), 8) = "THE LINK" Then
    Name = Replace(rs.Fields("Security Description"), "THE ", "")
Else
    Name = rs.Fields("Security Description 1")
    End If

loDataWrk.Cells(cnt, 1) = Name
loDataWrk.Cells(cnt, 2) = CLng(rs.Fields("Settled Shares/Par"))

cnt = cnt + 1
rs.MoveNext
Loop



Range("A3:B" & cnt - 1).Sort Key1:=Range("A3"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
conn.Close

path = "L:\Axys38\txt\"
file2 = "tou"
conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE" _
        & ".OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & path _
        & ";Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;" _
        & "FMT=TabDelimited'"
**rs.Open "Select * From " & file2 & ".txt order by [Security]", _
       conn, adOpenStatic, adLockUnspecified, adCmdText**


cnt = 3
Do While Not rs.EOF
loDataWrk.Cells(cnt, 3) = rs.Fields("Security")
loDataWrk.Cells(cnt, 4) = rs.Fields("Quantity")
loDataWrk.Cells(cnt, 5) = "=B" & cnt & "-D" & cnt
cnt = cnt + 1
rs.MoveNext
Loop

conn.Close
End Function
```

Below are two .txt files. The second one works (w/o changing any coding just referencing to it) and the first one doesn't. They're being split out by the same script. They seem to have the same formatting and the same headers... I dont't understand what i could possibly change.

```
Security Symbol Security    Quantity    Local ISO   Price   Spot Rate   Total Cost  Unrealized Gain/Loss    Market Value
AAAA    AAAAA   10000   SGD 1.23    1.2762  13089.5278  -748.20 12341.3258
BBBB    BBBBB   494 USD 23.45   1.0000  13011.6900  -1427.39    11584.3000



Security Symbol Security    Quantity    Local ISO   Price   Spot Rate   Total Cost  Unrealized Gain/Loss    Market Value
AAA AAAAA   18200   JPY 21.90   97.9000 486611.8961 -88033.76   398578.1410
```

Comment: does it mean that this sub is working with others of your text files except one of them?

Comment: yes exactly. i just copy and pasted of the other subs and changed the appropriate parts.

Comment: Ok. i guess it's something to do with that .txt file. I've tried to pull in the other .txt files and they work. Its the same script thats used for the output of all the files so i'm unsure of why'd it come out different. I'll play around with that.

Comment: yes, that is good way to go as a next step. if you need further support you would rather have to show your text file to compare and analyse. Good luck!

Comment: can't seem to figure out what the difference between the two .txt files is. I double checked everything. It's just not reading the [Security] part.

Comment: one is tou.txt & the other is mont.txt. tou is the one that's not working. if i put any other file in place of the tou, it works.

Comment: I don't expect it help but try to change your sql line into: `rs.Open "Select * From [" & file2 & ".txt] order by [Security]", conn, adOpenStatic, adLockUnspecified, adCmdText` where I added two square brackets.

Comment: additional suggestion- aren't there some empty rows at the end of `tou.txt` file? or any other different lines at the end of the file? one more- what if you try to import both text files to excel- is importing process result with the same structure?

Comment: no that gives me the same error.

Comment: yes i've tried to c&p into excel and it pastes the same way. I'm thinking it does have something to do with formatting but i cant figure out what and why.

Comment: if you can't figure it out you could upload your text files somewhere to have a look into them...

Comment: i've tried pasting data from other txt files that work. I've copied formatting from other txt files in excel and pasted it back in. We've upgraded Microsoft Office.. is there any way that could be an issue?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwdFfE5AFFtSVjBNd2I2NW04OUE/edit?usp=sharing
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwdFfE5AFFtSRTFrNVhVU2ZSWWc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add `schema.ini` file to solve your problems. So, according to [this information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms709353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you need to go as follows:

1.create text file `schema.ini` and save it in the folder where your `tou.txt` file is located.

2.your `schemat.ini` should looks like:

```
[Tou.Txt]
ColNameHeader = True
CharacterSet = ANSI
Format=TabDelimited
```

Now your code should works for `Tou.Txt` but could not for other files if they are all in the same folder. If so, you need to add to your `schema.ini` similar sections for all other text files you import.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! that worked. i have no idea what that file is or what it really does... ill research later but that worked. It was there before for all the other files just needed to include tou.txt