# VBA error while querying a Tab limited Text file with headers - "no value given for one or more required parameters"

Tags: sql, excel, vba

My Text file is Tab delimited and does have the **header Field** `"Datum"`. I intend to read the data between two given timestamps (along rows) into an Excel File and figured using the ADO and SQL approach would be the best way to go about it, since this would avoid use of arrays and looping.

My Text file looks like:

[image]

```
    Sub FetchZaehlerData()

        Dim wb As Workbook
        Set wb = ThisWorkbook
        Dim myConn As New ADODB.Connection
        Dim myRecordSet As New ADODB.Recordset
        Dim mySQLQry As String
        
        Dim myFSO As Object
        Set myFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Dim myFilePath As String
        
        myFilePath = "P:\PROJECTFILES\O&M\Metering Data\2020\01_2020\LS20200201"
        
        myConn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                "Data Source=" & myFilePath & ";" & _
                "Extended Properties='text;HDR=YES';"
                
        
        
        mySQLQry = "SELECT [Datum] FROM [TenneT2_P802_20200201064325.txt]"
        
        Debug.Print mySQLQry
        
        myRecordSet.Open mySQLQry, myConn
        
        wb.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("F3").CopyFromRecordset myRecordSet
        
        myRecordSet.Close
        myConn.Close
    
    Exit Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to specify `FMT=TabDelimited` in the Extended Properties part of the ConnectionString
2. You need to provide a schema.ini file, as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17304323/no-value-given-for-one-of-more-required-parameters)

It's unfortunate that the error message doesn't relate in any way to the problem you are having, but if you fix the two points I make, "it should all just work".